# Reduce the Classic Bluetooth range of ESP 32-Wroom-32D microcontroller

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, esp32

I am working on ESP 32-Wroom-32D microcontroller and using the in-built classic Bluetooth to connect to the android device. Currently, the microcontroller range is around 70 m and I want to reduce it to around 5 - 6 meters. Is there any possible way to reduce the Bluetooth range. Please find the code snippet.

```cpp
#include "DHT.h"
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
#include "BLEDevice.h"
#include <esp_bt.h>

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

#define DHTPIN 23
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
  dht.begin();
  //esp_power_level_t(ESP_PWR_LVL_N12);
}

void loop() {

  if (SerialBT.available() == 0);
  esp_power_level_t(ESP_PWR_LVL_N12);
  Serial.println(ESP_PWR_LVL_N12);
  delay(2000);
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
        
  // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
  if (isnan(f)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }
  SerialBT.print(f);
  //Serial.println(f);

  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: See https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/bluetooth/controller_vhci.html#_CPPv420esp_ble_tx_power_set20esp_ble_power_type_t17esp_power_level_t

Comment: @hcheung I tried this method and I think this method is used for Bluetooth low energy. In the code snippet, I used myDevice.setPower(ESP_PWR_LVL_N0), which sets the tx power to 0 dBm. When i uploaded the code to the board, it didn't work.

Comment: [esp_bt.h](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/f91080637/components/bt/include/esp_bt.h#L33) supports all mode as far as I can tell. 0dm is 1mW and is not low power. Did you set it to [other levels](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/f91080637/components/bt/include/esp_bt.h#L225) like N9(-9dbm) or N12(-12dbm)?

Comment: @hcheung I implemented the power level method as you mentioned before, Please check my updated code in the post. Since the esp_power_level_t(ESP_PWR_LVL_N12) is an enum and when I print the  ESP_PWR_LVL_N12 in the serial monitor, it displays the correct index number as stated in the datasheet. Still, my phone Bluetooth stays connected to the device no matter how far I go.